# ¿Cómo actualizar en BD dos tablas relacionales con EntityManager?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

Tengo un servicio que debe actualizar en dos tablas **Ajustes** y **Valores** ya que tienen la siguiente relación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo mi siguiente clase donde obtengo los 2 parámetros que quiero actualizar

```html
public class ClasePruebaImpl{
     @Setter
     private PruebaOperacion pruebaOperacion;
     
     public void actualizar(final ClaseEntrada){
     
        pruebaOperacion.operacionActualizar(claseEntrada.getComponente(), claseEntrada.getModulo());
     }
     
}
```

y esta es la clase que debe realizar la lógica de actualización, donde Ajustes y Valores son las clases Entidad, que ya están mapeadas pero no se como se realiza la actualizacion con persist

```html
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PruebaOperacion{

 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "USER_PU")
  private EntityManager entityManager;
 
  @Interceptors(CheckpointMonitor.class)
  public void operacionActualizar(Integer componente, Integer modulo){
  
    //Entidades
    final Ajustes ajustes = new Ajustes();
    final Valores valores = new Valores();
  
  }
 
}
```

Este es un query de como implemento el update pero no se como se haria para que en mi clase se haga la actualizacion en dichas tablas, que mètodos se usa, el persist? o el save?

```html
UPDATE USER_PU.AJUSTES SET VALOR = 'Nuevo valoe 99'
WHERE TIPO = 'NEW' AND LLAVE= 'PRUEBA_COMPONENTE_A';

UPDATE USER_PU.VALORES SET VALOR= '99'
WHERE ID_AJUSTE = (SELECT ID_AJUSTE FROM USER_PU.AJUSTES WHERE TIPO = 'NEW' AND LLAVE = 'PRUEBA_COMPONENTE_A');
```

Estas son mis Entidades Mapeadas

```html
@Entity
@Table(name ="Valores", shema="USER_PU")
@SequenceGenerator(name="Valores", sequenceName="USER_PU.SEQ.Valores", allocationSize =1)
@Data
public class Valores implements Serializable{
    
    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Valores")
@Column(name="ID_VALOR", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer idValor;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ID_AJUSTE", referencedColumnName = "ID_AJUSTE", 
  nullable=false)
private Ajustes ajustes;


@Column(name="VALOR")
private Integer valor;

@Column(name="DESCRIPCION")
private String descripcion;

@Column(name="CANAL")
private String canal;

}




@Entity
@Table(name ="Ajustes", shema="USER_PU")
@SequenceGenerator(name="Ajustes", sequenceName="USER_PU.SEQ.AJJSTES", allocationSize =1)
@Data
public class Ajuestes implements Serializable{
    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="Ajustes")
@Column(name="ID_AJUSTE", unique=true, nullable=false)
private Integer idAjuste;

@Column(name="TIPO")
private String tipo;

@Column(name="LLAVE")
private String llave;

@Column(name="VALOR")
private String valor;

@Column(name="DESCRIPCION")
private String descripcion;

@Column(name="ALCANCE")
private String alcance;

}
```

Comment: Si estás usando Hibernate/JPA, no es necesario escribir los updates. Definiste tus entities, y la relación entre ellas? Si es así agrégalas a la pregunta, y si no, investiga como definir entities y sus relaciones.

Comment: no estoy usando Hibernate, el mapeo de entidades ya las tengo, pero como se hace el update

Comment: Estas usando JPA o Hibernate porque tienes @PersistenceContext por ejemplo.
Por eso te digo, agrega tus entities (ajustes, valores) a la pregunta para poder ver si están correctamente definidas.

Comment: ya agregue mis entidades mapeadas, como posria ser con JPA o con Hibernate el update?

Comment: Claro, te falta relacionar una entidad con la otra, ya sea con \@OneToOne o \@OneToMany (no sé como será tu caso). Ya te digo, investiga como hacer eso y te va a quedar todo más claro.

Comment: ya lo agregue, pero de ahi como seria?